# Android: Characters not supported in custom font showing up as blanks

Tags: android, fonts, android-edittext

I'm attempting to use the Neucha font from Google Font Directory ([link](http://code.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Neucha&subset=latin)) in my Android app.

With other custom fonts, unsupported characters are still displayed, such as Japanese characters, as well as accented characters. However with the Neucha font, most unsupported characters (such as Asian ones) are displayed, but some accented characters (â, ã, ä, å, ą, ô, õ, ö, ő for example) are not displayed. Instead blank spaces are shown in their places.

Is this an issue with the font, or with Android? What can I do to get characters not supported by this font to be displayed using the default font in an EditText view? Thanks!

Comment: Any success, Stuck in similar problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Letters were omitted because of font.
2. Usage of multiple typefaces inside single TextView/ EditView is possible. You may use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan.html) class.

   `SpannableString string = new SpannableString("test");`

   string.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(myTypeface),0,2,0);
3. In order to use custom fonts in same way you may implement your own Span class.
   [here]http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan.java) is code sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
What can I do to get characters not supported by this font to be displayed using
the default font in an EditText view?
```

To my knowledge, it is impossible to have two separate fonts used in the same EditText *at the same time*.

Comment: If that is true, then how is it that the EditText is displaying Asian characters, which are certainly not in the font? It must be defaulting somehow for those characters.

Comment: Those characters are part of the extended ASCII table.  It doesn't surprise me at all that they are displayed.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean? I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with how this works. Does this mean the only way to fix the problem is to add characters to the font? Thanks!